# MVC4, Jquery how to make collapsible div work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I am developing an email reading application . It's MVC4 application.
The contents are loaded in a partial view.
Here is the entire code of the partial view:

```
@model List<MailServer.MailObject>

<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
<table width="75%" align="left">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="10%" ><input type="checkbox" id="chkSel" /> </th> <th width="30%">From</th><th width="40">Subject</th><th width="15%">Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach (MailServer.MailObject mail in Model)
{
    <tr> 
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>
            @mail.From
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:showdetail(@mail.MailID)">@mail.Subject </a> </td>
        <td>@mail.Sendtime</td>

    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
               <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
               <div class="collapsible-body"><p>@Html.Raw(@mail.Body)</p></div>
            </li>
          </ul>  
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Question is how to make the collapsible div to work. So that only the from, subject, sentdate are visible and body remains hidden below. Once the user clicks on it, the body should be visible.

The reference to jquery. jquery-ui are in Layout page, so not shown here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your scripts including the `showdetail()` function

Comment: hi Stephen, that code showdetail(), is remnent from old code. Actually the body is displaying in >@Html.Raw(@mail.Body). No javascript involved in separately displaying the body. the body now comes in one line below the subject line. So it is unmanageable. I was attempting to hide the body in collapsible div, which is not working.I have added jquery UI and  the code for accordion is added in the top of layout page but still it doesn't  work. So I needed help. I hope you understand.

Comment: You mentioned jquery-ui, so assuming you want to use that accordion all you need is `<div id="accordion">` containing heading (say `<h3>`) elements followed by `<div>` elements containing the 'collapsed' content. Refer the [demo here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default) - and view the source.